# Security camera installation problems

Tags: software-installation, camera

I'm having problems trying to install a Tenvis outdoor security camera on my computer running Ubuntu, I can't find or run the search tools.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What you've done so far?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Please also [edit] to explain what "search tools" you are referring to that you cannot find or run.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to find the IP of your newly installed camera, you can either:

- check your router's DHCP leases (only if the camera uses DHCP to acquire an IP address), or
- use `nmap` to scan your entire network for devices that appear online (and finding out which IP is your camera's IP) with `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24`, assuming that your network is on the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet.